# UITableView custom plain gray index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5

I really need to implement a set of gray index bars for my app.

Currently, I'm using a UITableView which I split off into multiple sections.

However, the default section indexes have a gradient appearance which I think is undesirable.

Is it posssible to change the indexes to have a custom appearance such as a plain gray appearance?

If so how? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your custom "index view" ( section header ) by using these tableView delegate or datasource (I'm kind of blur) methods.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```